# Ruby on Rails User Authentication CRUD API Building

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, authentication

Stackoverflowers.
Hope you are doing well.
I recently started Ruby Stack, and I've tried to build CRUD of User Authentication.
I googled but, there are not perfect sample when I search.
Anyone provide relevant sample url or learning course guide?

Hope to help me soon.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the devise gem - https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn how to set up API user authentication on the backend *without* something like the devise gem (which can be a little intimidating and confusing for folks new to Ruby on Rails [I'm new to it too]), I'd suggest checking out the [bcrypt](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby) gem (for password encryption) and the [jwt](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt) gem (JSON Web Token).

This particular article seems like a useful walkthrough: https://medium.com/swlh/auth-with-json-web-tokens-bcrypt-part-i-rails-3afd71751ea

Comment: I appreciate that Devise comes with a learning curve; but it’s far better than the learning curve to write good security. I would strongly suggest that you invest your time learning Devise instead of trying to roll your own security. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own#18198 for more on this.

Comment: Respectfully, Devise's own documentation says: "If you are building your first Rails application, we recommend you do not use Devise. Devise requires a good understanding of the Rails Framework. In such cases, we advise you to start a simple authentication system from scratch... Once you have solidified your understanding of Rails and authentication mechanisms, we assure you Devise will be very pleasant to work with."

Comment: Fair enough; just don’t go deploying to production with what is a learning experience